# Shell script to prevent execution of a particular application

Tags: shell, terminal

I'm trying to write a script in Terminal that keeps you from being able to open a particular application.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ true ]; do

killall iChat

done
```

When I run the script I get a message that says "No matching processes belonging to you were found". What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Also I would like to run this script in bash so that when I `killall Terminal` it will continue to run. Currently when I `killall Terminal`, the whole script stops working.

How can this be done?

Comment: The brackets are unnecessary: 'while true; do' works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

This is not the way to prevent a process from being started.  What you need to do is `chown root.root /path/to/iChat` so the process is owned by `root` and then `chmod a-x /path/to/iChat`.  This will prevent the the process from being executable and the permissions can only be changed by root.

Answer (score 1):

The process won't be named iChat, but rather something like /Applications/iChat.app/Contents/MacOS/ichat . Use a regular expression with killall to kill processes with names that contain a given string:

killall -m iChat

Now, what's with the "while true?" This loop is going to run very quickly, pegging your CPU and not doing anything. Maybe you want to sleep for a while, at least?

Finally, to run the loop so that it kills terminals without killing the terminal where the script is running, just don't run it in a terminal -- run it in the background. Put it in a file, and say something like

killer &

Comment: Ok cool, now how do I go about running the code in the background? whats the code for that? I have the infinite loop in there so that every time the person tries to open the application it terminates at every attempt

Comment: Honestly, I think Slartibartfast's answer is better, in terms of solving the stated problem. But if you need to do this for some reason: running a command in the background is just a matter of following it with a "&" character. So in my answer above, that "&" in the last example runs the script "killer" in the background.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear why you need to do this, nor how determined your violators are.

If you are working against non-sophisticated violators, something similar to SiegeX's approach (chmod 500 / chmod a-x) will prevent the application from ever starting.

If you must do a kill after the fact, killall could work, but it is a touch risky (you run the risk of killing processes you didn't intend to kill).

Fundamentally though, the user can usually download the source (or a binary of their own) and compile and run the software that way.  This task is very hard.